# How can I loop through all of the P tags and then write their innerHTML to the document at the end of the page?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to loop through all of the p tags on my web page and then write them to the end of the web page. I thought that this for loop would work but so far it is giving me an error.

How would I be able to do this and then append the text that is in the

tag to the end of the page?

```
function forLoopTest() {
    var i; //indexing tag for looping through all of the array elements

    //for loop to loop through the pp array starting at index of zero 
    for (i = 0; i < pp.length;i++) 
    {
       document.writeln("<br>" + pp[i].innerHTML); //write to the end of the page of each element
    }
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="main">
    <p id="AA">A</p>
    <p id="BB">B</p>
    <p id="CC">C</p>
    <p id="DD">D</p>
    <p id="EE">E</p>
</div>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
    var x = document.getElementById("main");
    var pp = x.getElementsByTagName("p"); //creates an array of p elements
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'The first paragraph inside "main" is ' + pp[1].innerHTML;

function forLoopTest() {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < pp.length;i++) {
       document.writeln("<br>" + pp[i].innerHTML;
    }
}

forLoopTest();
</script>

</body>
</html>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="main">
<div id="main">
    <p id="AA">A</p>
    <p id="BB">B</p>
    <p id="CC">C</p>
    <p id="DD">D</p>
    <p id="EE">E</p>
</div>

<p id="demo"></p>
<p style="color:blue;margin-left:20px;">This is a paragraph.</p>
    <p id="A">A</p>
    <p id="B">B</p>
    <p id="C">C</p>
    <p id="D">D</p>
    <p id="E">E</p>
    <div>Test</div>
</div>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
    var x = document.getElementById("main");
    var pp = x.getElementsByTagName("p"); //creates an array of p elements
    var divTag = x.getElementsByTagName("div"); //creates an array of div elements
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'The first paragraph inside "main" is ' + pp[1].innerHTML;

function forLoopTest() {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < pp.length;i++) {
       document.writeln("<br>" + pp[i].innerHTML;
    }
}

var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName('p'), function (element) {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(element.childNodes, function (childNode) {
        fragment.appendChild(childNode.cloneNode(true));
    });
});

document.body.appendChild(fragment);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Dont use document.write/writeln. Dont do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are numerous way to do it, one solution might be.

HTML

```
<div id="main">
    <p id="AA">A</p>
    <p id="BB">B</p>
    <p id="CC">C</p>
    <p id="DD">D</p>
    <p id="EE">E</p>
</div>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Javascript

```
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName('p'), function (element) {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(element.childNodes, function (childNode) {
        fragment.appendChild(childNode.cloneNode(true));
    });
});

document.body.appendChild(fragment);
```

HTML after

```
<div id="main">
    <p id="AA">A</p>
    <p id="BB">B</p>
    <p id="CC">C</p>
    <p id="DD">D</p>
    <p id="EE">E</p>
</div>
<p id="demo"></p>
ABCDE
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/t7nb9/)

> Warning: [cloneNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode)() may lead to duplicate element IDs in a
>   document.

This is also true if blindly copying the `innerHTML` of the elements.

Answer (score 1):

if you read the error it tells you you have a syntax problem and are misisng a `)`.

You didn't close `write()`

```
document.writeln("<br>" + pp[i].innerHTML;
```

Should be

```
document.writeln("<br>" + pp[i].innerHTML);
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/aUSJlaxoVNrS5edaBOIb?p=preview)**</kbd>